# Encoding characters with ISO 8859-1 in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

With `ord(ch)` you can get a numerical code for character `ch` up to `127`. Is there any function that returns a number from 0-255, so to cover also `ISO 8859-1` characters?
**Edit:** Follows my last version of code and error I get

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: iso-8859-1

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('iso-8859-1')
print sys.getdefaultencoding()  # prints "iso-8859-1" 

def char_code(c):
    return ord(c.encode('iso-8859-1'))
print char_code(u'à')
```

I get an error:
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're starting with a Unicode string, you need to `encode` rather than `decode`.

```
>>> def char_code(c):
        return ord(c.encode('iso-8859-1'))

>>> print char_code(u'à')
224
```

For ISO-8859-1 in particular, you don't even need to encode it at all, since Unicode uses the ISO-8859-1 characters for its first 256 code points.

```
>>> print ord(u'à')
224
```

Edit: I see the problem now. You've given a [source code encoding comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) that indicates the source is in ISO-8859-1. However, I'll bet that your editor is actually working in UTF-8. The source code will be mis-interpreted, and the single-character string you think you created will actually be two characters. Try the following to see:

```
print len(u'à')
```

If your encoding is correct, it will return `1`, but in your case it's probably `2`.

Comment: I tried both ways you suggest,but I still get the same error.

Comment: @DrimadesBoy then your example is incorrect, please update it with code that actually demonstrates the error.

Comment: Solved. I'm using Geany in Ubuntu and changed the file encoding from 'utf-8' to 'iso-8859-1' from Document > Set Encoding > Western European > ISO-8859-1

Comment: @DrimadesBoy if it's solved, please use the checkbox so everybody knows it. And an upvote would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `ord()` for anything. As you might expect, [`ord(u'')`](http://ideone.com/MiP2zJ) works fine, provided you can represent the character properly in your source, and/or read it in a known encoding.

Your error message vaguely suggests that `coding: iso-8859-1` is not actually true, and the file's encoding is actually something else (UTF-8 or UTF-16 would be my guess).

The canonical must-read on character encoding in Python is http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Maybe see the [`character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `ord()`, but you have to decode it.

Like this:

```py
def char_code(c):
    return ord(c.decode('iso-8859-1'))
```

Comment: Using *print char_code(u'')*  I get: *Non-ASCII character '\xf0' in file unicode.py on line 4, but no encoding declared;*

Comment: This character does not exists in ISO-8859-1, [check the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: And you should specify an [encoding header](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: The error message suggests the `coding:` header is wrong.  If you declare ISO-8859-1 encoding, but the actual encoding of the file is UTF-8 (or UTF16) that's the error message you would expect.